# How to fix empty Docker LogPath

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I’m setting up a new Redis server via docker-compose and cannot find json docker log file.

Redis log are **/dev/stdout** and visible via **docker-compose logs** command.

Docker version 1.13.1, build 7f2769b/1.13.1

docker-compose version 1.24.1, build 4667896

**docker inspect --format='{{.LogPath}}' docker-compose-redis_redis_1** shows nothing

Snippet from docker-compose.yml:

```
    logging:
    #limit logs to 200MB (4rotations of 50M each)
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "50m"
        max-file: "4"
```

I expect to find json file in /var/lib/docker/containers/container-id/

Comment: I'm hitting the same issue but only when using non-blocking mode, are u using that too?.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to docker-compose:

```
logging:
  driver: "json-file"
```

Im not sure yet to figure out how to change system wide, but I noticed I'm using `journald` default.

```
cat /etc/docker/daemon.json.original
{
    "log-driver": "journald",
    "storage-driver": "overlay2"
}
```